# Groups of two words in a phrase. C#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

How do I know how many groups of two words exist in a phrase?

this is my Code

```
        var str = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5";

        Console.WriteLine(str.CountGroupWords(2));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The result should be: 2 because word1 and word2 is a group and word3 and word4 is other group, word5 is not part of any group

Exists a regex pattern for solve this problem?

Comment: can you post the code in the CountGroupWords method to check

Comment: Regular expressions are not the answer to all problems!

Comment: yep, but what's wrong with adding an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex solution.

Will match only words with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` Also neglecting any multiple spaces

Example :

```
 string para= "word1    word2 word3 word4 word5"; // <= include multiple splaces
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w+");

 Console.WriteLine((reg.Matches(para).Count) /2);
```

Output :

```
2
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't need Regex, you can can find spaces count and divide by 2:

```
 var result = str.Count(x => x == ' ') / 2;
```

***If it contains more than one space***, then you can try [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method overload which takes [`StringSplitOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) as a second parameter with the value `RemoveEptryEntries`. Then the return value *does not include* array elements that contain an *empty string*:

```
var result = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length / 2;
```

Comment: Thanks!. If the str contains more than one space between words?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex and then count the number of matches.

```
@"\S+\s+\S+"
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters where `\s+` matches one or more space characters.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW8kZ0/1)

```
String input = @"word1 word2 word3 word4 word5";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\S+\s+\S+");
int NumberOfTrues = rgx.Matches(input).Count;
Console.WriteLine(NumberOfTrues);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/FwWUvc)